# OpenId library (include files are not found by script)

Tags: php, openid

I have been trying to implement openid functionality into my website. I downloaded the JanRain's library.

I extracted the 'Auth' folder in my classes directory and following the example in the 'example' folder I created the try_auth.php, finish_auth.php, common.php file in the include directory.

Now when I click on the openid selector link I am presented with an error message that says 'openid.php' file not found.

This file is present in the Auth directory.

I corrected it and then I am being presented with a different error which says 'Auth/Yadis/HTTPFetcher.php' not found.

If I sit and change the require path individually in every file in the auth folder then it will take a long time.

my apps directory structure is like this 
app 
  classes 
     Auth (openid library)
  config
  elements
  includes
  views
  webroot
  index.php

Please help me what am I doing wrong. How do I set the includepath so that all the files take their respective paths automatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[as the documentation states](http://openidenabled.com/files/php-openid/docs/2.1.3/) (you don't mention a version, so i am assuming you are using 2.x.x), the `Auth/` directory in this package has to be in your PHP [include path](http://php.net/ini.core#ini.include-path). there are [various ways](http://php.net/configuration) to do that: `php.ini`, `httpd.conf`/`.htaccess`, `ini_set()`, ... if you do it in your `php.ini`, with your apps directory being `/path/to/your/app`, it would look like that:

```
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
include_path = ".:/php/includes:/path/to/your/app/classes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2" or "c:/path1;c:/path2"
;include_path = ".;c:/php/includes;c:/path/to/your/app/classes"
```

Comment: :-)
thanks Mr. ax
I think your solution seems to be an effective one, will try it soon.

thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The files are there you're just not setting the path correctly.

You said this is the path it's looking for 'Auth/Yadis/HTTPFetcher.php'
You might need to add the full path, something like this:

```
/var/www/html/whaterver/Auth/Yadis/HTTPFetcher.php
```

or

```
/this/is/where/you/put/the/path/to/the/file/Auth/Yadis/HTTPFetcher.php
```

just do this command to find the base path and append it to your file path

```
echo `pwd`;
```

NOTE: those are backticks not single quotes around the pwd command

EDIT:

You just need to add this to the file that your trying to include into your script.

EXAMPLE:

your file is here: /var/www/html/index.php

and you need to include this file here: /classes/package/files.php

This file: /classes/package/files.php know where all the other files are that come in the package, so no need to edit any of these.

But you do need to edit the /var/www/html/index.php file and add something lie this:

```
include('/var/www/html/classes/packages/files.php');
```

once you have this in your script it should know where everything else is.

or as @ax has stated this looks to be a php.ini configuration

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
:-D
Dear,
There are around 40 files in the 'Auth' folder. You still want me to do this for every file.?
If I do this then It will take a really long time. I bet there is a better solution for this. Isn't it.?

Comment: No not for every file but the file that includes those files to your script.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the include path with the `set_include_path` function call ([`http://php.net/set_include_path`](http://php.net/set_include_path)), if that's what you're asking...

Answer (score 0):

Do a **getcwd** to find the directory you are in and make the appropiate **chdir**(**s**) to resolve your problem. It is a dirty solution but it should work with a minimal effort.

Comment: I would have done that already if It was able to solve my prob. :-)